# Objective question closed as being 'not constructive'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15148852/146622):

> In .Net 4.5 Microsoft has added the new `Async/Await` feature to simplify asynchronous coding in it; However, I wonder
>
> 1. is `Async/Await` came to completely replace the old way of using
>      `Threads` ?
> 2. is `Async/Await` capable of doing what ever a `Thread` can do
>      asynchronously ?
> 3. is `Async/Await` only can be used with some methods like
>      `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` or can i convert any Synchronous
>      method to make it use `Async/Await` and not to block the main thread?
>
> Finding detailed answers for the questions above really interests me so i decided to ask them here at `stackoverflow` to get the best explanation.

...was closed on the grounds of being 'not constructive', while the question is not subjective.

If you could look at the close-reasons given, I suspect they won't all be 'not constructive'. This is an indication that the question is not closed for any valid close reason, but only because people feel the asker has not put enough (reaearch) effort in the question.

However, putting not enough effort in a question *is not a valid reason to close a question* (that's what downvotes are for). I request **for the question to be reopened**.

Comment: I wonder what gives you the idea that everyone did not vote "Not Constructive". And for the record, "Not a Real Question" *can* certainly be a legitimate close reason for questions that show no research effort, among other problems. If there isn't enough research effort to be able to answer the question, or understand it...

Comment: Also, for the record; though I am one of those who voted to close, I'm not against it being reopened, either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's actually not constructive, but skimming the question the last paragraph has elements that immediately raise flags:

> Finding detailed answers for the questions above really interests me so i decided to ask them here at `stackoverflow` to get the best explanation.

- It's chatty / has no relevance to the question
- Using code formatting for something that's not code
- Using subjective words like "best" and "really interests me"

Also, in the first paragraph "I wonder" is also typical of non-constructive questions.

So *if* it's actually a viable question, it's written in a pattern that many not constructive questions follow which would explain people voting to close it.

Comment: Well, I hope formatting and chattyness are not your criteria for closing a question. Unless lack of formatting or chattyness becomes a problem for the question itself, which is not the case here. Usually chattyness and formatting problems are easily edited away by fellow users. It's the easiest kind of edit one can make.

Comment: No, they are not criteria for closing a question, but you seem to have missed the point here: the question *looks like* it's not constructive, so people tend to vote to close. (Note that I did not do so, and note that I'm not saying that the question should have been closed.) There are so many bad questions posted all the time that there's really no point in pausing to investigate each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not at all clear. If *I* "translate" it this is what I come up with:

> is Async/Await came to completely replace the old way of using Threads ?

Will Async/Await come to completely replace the old way of using Threads? - This is asking for 
people opinion and isn't constructive.

> is Async/Await capable of doing what ever a Thread can do asynchronously ?

The same - okay(ish), haven't they read the manual?

> is Async/Await only can be used with some methods like WebClient.DownloadStringAsync or can i convert any Synchronous method to make it use Async/Await and not to block the main thread?

Can Async/Await only can be used with some methods like `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` or can I convert any synchronous method to make it use Async/Await and not to block the main thread? - okay(ish), haven't they read the manual?

Simply put the question is hard to understand and my interpretation of it is that the question is not constructive. I wouldn't have voted to close necessarily I'd have asked the OP to clarify their first question and then voted to close if they didn't.  I'm wary of editing point 1 out as I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct.

In tags with a lot of questions, like C#, I can fully understand people voting immediately.

Comment: I understood the question more in the sense of: `A` is a new feature to C#. Is `A` meant to completely replace `B`; capable of doing what `B` did; can `A` be used on existing `C` or convert it to work that way? While I can somewhat understand how you can interpret it as _asking for opinions_, you could actually say that about most of the questions that are asked, even those that are voted up and never closed.